# Is there an annotation that triggers a warning if an object is passed that captures enclosing ‘this’?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, reference-cycle

I have a Kotlin function with this signature:

```
fun registerDisposer(obj: Any, disposer: Closeable)
```

What the function does is attach `disposer` to a phantom reference and arrange it to be closed when `obj` is garbage-collected (i.e. when the phantom reference object is enqueued). The class of `obj` is supposed to call it something like this:

```
class Holder(private val res1: Closeable, private val res2: Closeable) {
    init {
        registerDisposer(this, object: Closeable {
            private val res1 = this@Holder.res1
            private val res2 = this@Holder.res2

            override fun close() {
                res1.close()
                res2.close()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

(Let’s ignore whether this is a good idea to rely on this with general `Closeable`s; the *actual* resource in question is a pointer managed by native/JNI code – I am trying to follow [Hans Boehm’s advice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_caITSjk1k&t=19m42s). But all of this is not particularly relevant for this question.)

I am worried that this design makes it too easy to inadvertently pass an object that captures `this` from the outer scope, creating a reference loop and preventing the object from being garbage-collected at all:

```
registerDisposer(this, Closeable {
    this.res1.close()
    this.res2.close()
})
```

Is there an annotation I can add to the `disposer` parameter that will trigger a warning in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, the answer seems to be: probably not.

It turns out a `registerDisposer` function already exists as the `register` method of `java.lang.ref.Cleaner`, and it has no such annotation.

In Android, there is a similar annotation for `android.os.AsyncTask`, but that simply warns at any anonymous object having `AsyncTask` as its base class, whether it captures `this` or not. (This makes sense in Java, where anonymous classes always capture `this`, but not in Kotlin.)